# Remove / Filter Cell Contents in Microsoft Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am looking for the best way to clean up the cell contents of one particular cell in my spreadsheet. As it exists now, Column D lists a City, State, and High School in the same cell (Screenshot #1). I need to split these values out into 3 unique columns/cells as shown in Screenshot #2. How would I accomplish this?

** Note - The example below is just a sample size. I have thousands of cells to perform this on.

**Existing cell format:**

[image]

**New Format (Hopefully):**

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This should be fairly trivial. Is your question about optimization? (if so, please show your current code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Text-to-Columns "delimited" to split on the comma, then use it again "fixed width" to split the state from the school name (assuming the state is always 2 characters). Clean up spaces with TRIM if required.

Answer (score 0):

Hi something like this should look through all your cells in row D and return the values you are looking for in the next 3 columns; might need a little adjusting

`For each cell in Range("D2:D & Range("D2".End(xlDown).Row))
cell.offset(columnOffset:=1) = left(cell,instr(String1:=cell, String2:= ","))
cell.offset(columnOffset:=2) = Mid(cell,instr(String1:=cell, String2:= ",")+1,2)
cell.offset(columnOffset:=3) = right(cell,len(cell)-instr(String1:=cell, String2:= ",")+3) 
Next`

Answer (score 0):

I tried Jake Duddy's code it contains quite some errors, I do not know if it works. At the same time you can try below code.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim State_L As String
Dim City_L As String
Dim HS_L As String

LastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To LastRow

    City_L = Left(Range("D" & i), InStr(1, Range("D" & i), ",") - 1) ' Getting up to comma
    State_L = Mid(Range("D" & i), InStr(1, Range("D" & i), ",") + 1, 2) 'Getting after comma for 2 characters
    HS_L = Mid(Range("D" & i), InStr(1, Range("D" & i), ",") + 3, Len(Range("D" & i)) - InStr(1, Range("D" & i), ",")) 'Getting after comma+2 characters upto the end

    Range("E" & i).Value = City_L
    Range("F" & i).Value = State_L
    Range("G" & i).Value = HS_L

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

**Select** the cells you wish to process and run this small macro:

```
Sub ParseData()
    Dim r As Range, L As Long, L1 As Long, L2 As Long

    For Each r In Selection
        t = r.Text
        L = Len(t)
        L1 = InStr(1, t, ",")
        For i = 1 To L
            If r.Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic = True Then
                L2 = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid(t, 1, L1 - 1)
        r.Offset(0, 2).Value = Mid(t, L1 + 1, L2 - L1 - 1)
        r.Offset(0, 3) = Mid(t, L2)
        r.Offset(0, 3).Font.Italic = True
    Next r
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]